# How do I query sql.NullTime value from sql in golang stored in the format 2023-06-08 19:54:41 +0000

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, go

```
    currentTime := time.Now().UTC().Format(layout)
    prevTime := time.Now().UTC().Add(-time.Minute * 15).Format(layout)
    currTime, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", currentTime)
    previousTime, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", prevTime)
    query := `
        SELECT *
        from %s
        where
        updated_on_utc > %v
        and
        updated_on_utc <= %v`
    query = fmt.Sprintf(query, TableName, previousTime, currTime)
    data := db.DbClient.ExecuteQuery(query)
```

this gives out the error message : panic: Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '19:54:41 +0000 UTC
and
updated_on_utc <= 2023-06-08 20:09:41 +0000 UTC' at line 4

I have tried different queries with different placeholders but all of them give the same error

Comment: updated_on_utc > '%v'

Comment: tried that as well
the result is returned as null when there should be a timestamp for sure meeting the criteria

Comment: Don't hand craft SQL. Let the DB driver use prepared statements or queries with placeholder parameters. It's safer & easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you mentioned here, I'm understanding that the column `updated_on_utc` is of type text(`time.Parse` function is used to retrieve the text), you have to change the query to the following:

```
SELECT *
    from %s
    where
    updated_on_utc > "%v"
    and
    updated_on_utc <= "%v"
```

Please don't use string formatters([Why should we use query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)), you need to use query parameters like below:

```
    SELECT *
    from %s
    where
    updated_on_utc > ?
    and
    updated_on_utc <= ?
```

Then change your code as below:

```
query = fmt.Sprintf(query, "your_table_name")
_, err = db.Query(query, previousTime, currTime)
```

As the time is stored in DB as string, the query won't return the desired result. So you need to change the type to `datetime` or `timestamp`.